# SEO for mutiple store

Tags: seo

We have an online store in Canada and have been doing pretty well with a steadily increasing customer coming a lot from google. When we search for related products in www.google.ca, we are pretty much always on the first page of the organic results. We have decided about 3 months ago to create a second website in our magento (this one is for US customers and is a different domain). However we noticed that we do not have any traffic on google for the new domain. Does anyone have any clues or links where we can look into SEO when we have mutiple website on magento?

Answer (score 0):

It not like you work on a website, ranking it higher and so the other website you work should also rank the same. Ranking is not like a cloud service that syncs your progress & achievement on new devices.

Dude, you are on a new domain, another one. Its a new job now. You gotta start from zero. You might have to apply all the strategies again that you adopted for your last work, or even implement the new ones.

Its like building your new place. Suppose, You have a villa. It doesn't mean that you can replicate the same thing directly without any efforts. You have to start from placing bricks to bricks.

But Yes, you can establish the same place by applying the same strategies, smartly.

Answer (score -6):

For new E-commerce website it takes times & efforts to take off your to the first page of SERP.

My suggestion is to do Local SEO For USA Location, Also optimize product & Keywords accordingly.

To rank in the top of the google and getting organic traffic from SERP build SEO strategy and find out your competitor and find out from where they get a quality link and you get the link from those sites. That will help you.